# Find and forward specific emails in Yahoo.mail using Javascript

Tags: javascript, email

I am new at programing.  I am learning the basics of javascript right now.  I had an idea that sounded like something perfect for coding.  But I am wondering if it is even possible in JS:

I have a Yahoo email account with at least 3000 stored emails which need to be forwarded to a different email account, such as Google.  Yahoo (the greedy bastards) want me to pay for a program that will automatically forward a large amount of emails.  Otherwise I have to individually select one email at a time and forward it.  It's not all the emails in the Yahoo account, just specific ones from certain addresses.  But now that I am thinking in terms of programming, I had the idea that in theory it seems a relatively simple bit of JS coding to sort through emails from a few specific addresses, and forward them to my one other email address.

Is this possible?

I don't even know where to start with making the JS coding work with Yahoo.  Would I have to alter the way yahoo mail webpage functions in my browser?  Would it have to use the same language Yahoo uses, or is there a way to use JS into my copmuter, ie write a mini program which takes control of the yahoo mail webpage to complete this task?  My questions are probably way off base, and it's surely apparent to you that I am an utter n00b at this point.  Any information would be appreciated.

Thank you